# Find the largest possible radius for $S=[1,4) \cup (4,9]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, epsilon-delta

> Find max $\{\epsilon : N(x;\epsilon) \subseteq S\}$, the largest $\epsilon$ such that the neighborhood centered at $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ is contained in $S$.  That is, state the largest possible radius of an
>   open interval centered at $x$ and contained in $S$.

$x=7.2$

$S=[1,4) \cup (4,9]$

Based upon what I know so far, the largest possible radius of an open interval centered at $x$ and contained in $S$ would be (I imagine) the boundary points, which would be my $x-\epsilon$ and $x+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is equal to my boundary points.

Am I way off here?

Comment: Have you tried drawing yourself a picture?  Is it $\epsilon$ or is it $x+\epsilon$ which will be the boundary point?  Or will it in fact be $x-\epsilon$?  Which boundary point is closest to $7.2$?

Comment: @JMoravitz it would be $x-\epsilon$, right?

Comment: @JMoravitz for what it is worth, this is an online class and I haven't really learned any techniques for solving it other than what I've been reading in my books.  So a lot of this is very confusing to me.  Thanks for the 'drawing a picture' suggestion!

Comment: It depends on what $x$ is which would be closest.  If $x=4.2$ then the closest boundary point would be $4$, so the largest $\epsilon$-neighborhood around $4.2$ would be $(4,4.4)$  (*notice that $4.2$ is smack-dab in the middle of that interval*).  If $x=2.9$ then the largest $\epsilon$-neighborhood would be $(1.8,4)$  (*notice that $2.9$ is smack-dab in the middle of that interval*).  If $x=1$ then there is no $\epsilon$-neighborhood surrounding $1$.

Comment: If you want to state it generally, then you can use $\epsilon = \min(|x-d|)_{d\in\partial(S)}$ or some similar statement.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think I see the source of my confusion, I don't completely understand what the $\epsilon$-neighborhood is.  I'm trying to understand how you got the (4, 4.4) and (1.8,4).  I realize you're picking some arbitrary values of $x$ but how do you come up with an $\epsilon$?

Comment: @JMoravitz ohhh I see, it's just the difference between the $x$ and the boundary points

Comment: $N(x;\epsilon):= \{a~:~|x-a|<\epsilon\}$, the "*open ball of radius* $\epsilon$."  The largest of which, is as you recognize, the one which extends as close as possible to the boundary as it can.  I say "*ball*" because the concept works in higher dimensions as well.  In the standard borel sigma algebra on $\Bbb R$ that you are used to and working with, these "balls" are just intervals.  In $\Bbb R^3$ they are spheres (*with the insides too, not just the shell*).

Comment: @JMoravitz this makes much more sense to me now!  Thanks for your time

Comment: @JMoravitz I just realized our discussion centered around an arbitrary value of $x$, however, I have been give that $x=7.2$.  Thus, wouldn't my neighborhood have to be around $x=7.2$ and wouldn't I take the $\epsilon$ farthest away from from that point in its neighborhood?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41589/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-free-mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for the largest radius of an open interval centered at $x$ and contained in $S$, I want an $\epsilon$ that does not extend past my boundary points $\{4,9\}$

Since my boundary points are in $S$, I will use them to determine the largest radius.

Therefore I need to meet the following two conditions:

(1) $x-\epsilon\ge4$

(2) $x+\epsilon\le9$

Testing boundary (1) and setting $x=7.2$ I have $7.2-\epsilon \ge 4$ or $\epsilon \le 7.2-4=3.2$

If I use $\epsilon=3.2$ then $x-\epsilon=7.2-3.2=4$, which is in the set; however, $x+\epsilon=7.2+3.2=10.4$, which is not in the set.  So this boundary point does not work.

Testing boundary (2) and setting $x=7.2$ I have $7.2+\epsilon \le 9$ or $\epsilon \le 9-7.2 = 1.8$

If I use $\epsilon=1.8$ then $x-\epsilon=7.2-1.8=5.4$, which is in the set and $x+\epsilon=7.2+1.8=9$, which is also in the set.

So $1.8$ is the largest $epsilon$ in $S$ that meets the requirements.

Comment: Although $\epsilon$ happens to be in $S$, it need not necessarily be.  If $S$ was $(50,51]$ and $x$ was $50.1$,  $\epsilon$ would be $0.1$.  Be careful of phrasing.  $1.8$ is the largest $\epsilon$ such that *the neighborhood is in $S$* (even though $\epsilon$ is itself not an element of $S$)